# Position 2 div's one, above the other, both 100% of the screen height

Tags: html, css

I am aware that using the css

```
#fullpage{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

fills the entire page, however I want this, then below it, i.e one page length down, I want another space that is equal to 100% of the screens height.

So in theory I want two divs, both equal to 100% screen height and 100% screen width, one ontop of the other, equalling to 200% of the page height.

Any help guys?

Comment: Do you really need to use position absolute? Unless you need to remove them from the page flow you could just use position relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second div, add `top: 100%` in addition to the rules you already have.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/FZG49/

Answer (score 1):

No need for absolute positioning..

just reset the `html` and `body` and add two full width/height divs..

```
<div id="page-1"></div>
<div id="page-2"></div>
```

with

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#page-1, #page-2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: red;
}
#page-2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/FZG49/1/